# i want to print time since on posts

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i have a model post which has a created field so i cant print the day created, but it comes out as a full date while all i need is the time since i.e(3 hrs ago, not 21st Month/Year)

```
class post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Topic = models.ForeignKey(topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', default=None, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.post}'
    
    @property
    def num_likes(self):
        return self.liked.all().count()
```

my views.py

```
def index(request):
     posts = post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
     topics = topic.objects.all()
     comment = comments.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'base/home.html', {'posts' : posts, 'topics' : topics, 'comments' : comment})
```

in my template

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post-body-content">
    @{{post.author}} - <small><i>{{post.created}} </i></small> <br>
    Topic: <a href="{% url 'topic' post.Topic %}">{{post.Topic}}</a> <br>
    <a href="{% url 'post' post.id %}">{{post}}</a> <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the timesince template tags
as per django docs
[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)

{{post.created|timesince}}

for example

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="post-body-content">
@{{post.author}} - <small><i>{{post.created|timesince}} </i></small> <br>
Topic: <a href="{% url 'topic' post.Topic %}">{{post.Topic}}</a> <br>
<a href="{% url 'post' post.id %}">{{post}}</a> <br>
```